# Cocoa touch - GameKit GKPeerPickerController devices

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm now testing GKPeerPickerController.
I have a simple app that just have a button and do GKPeerPickerController on a device.
However, all it does is "Looking for other iPhones or iPod touches..."

I do have another device nearby with bluetooth turned on BUT without the app installed.
Does that other device also need to have the app installed?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The other device needs to have the app installed and running for it to be visible to GameKit in your code.

Comment: Hey Noah, thanks for the reply. So what determines what device will show? Is it the bundle identifier name?

Comment: Probably, yeah. I don't really know the internals, but any device running your app and broadcasting its presence via Bluetooth should show up in the peer picker controller of any other nearby instance of your app.

Comment: By default, it's the bundle ID that's used to match devices, but you can change that to any arbitrary string by passing a suitably configured GKSession object back to GameKit via the - (GKSession *)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type
 GKPeerPickerController delegate method.